# Electrodynamics- Could a strong negative charge near a mirror push away valence electrons and render it non-reflective?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, reflection

My understanding of electromagnetism would have me believe that since it is the waveform of the photon interacting with the conglomerate waveform of the "ocean" of electrons saturating a metal which induces metallic reflections, could you see what a metal really looks like if you pushed all the free electrons away?

A first surface mirror could be held in a dielectric housing to insulate it, and a strong negatively charged probe could be brought near it and repel the valence electron fluid away from the surface. This is analogous to waters receding exposing land beneath where it blocked view of it before due to its optical distortions. I know that we can produce free solvated electrons, but can we remove them from a chunk of metal to see what it looks like under the reflections?

Is this in fact already what we see for example with nanoparticles of gold during its refinement? I.E. the metal is not held together by its metallic bonds in this state and is thus non-reflective and hence shows its true colors? Similarly, Tin pest, an allotype of Tin is basically just this, and hence also is nonreflective, is it for this reason?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "could you see what a metal really looks like if you pushed all the free electrons away?" This strikes me as akin to asking "Could you see what the ocean really looks like if you pushed all the water away?" Well, you would see something, but nothing I would call an ocean.

Comment: @d_b that's a fair point, but I'm just asking if there would be a negation of the reflection when the surface electrons are pushed away by a strong negative charge